# How to diagnose CORS issues in .NET Core 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I was having issues with CORS whereby if I allow any method, any origin and any headers, everything worked fine, but the moment I constrain any of those the browser console instantly turned red.

I've since fixed my issue (it was due to a bad environment variable) but it was a rather tedious trial and error process.

Is there any way to diagnose CORS issues in .NET Core? Is the actual reason for the failure logged anywhere?

For the case above, it would've been very helpful if I could've found a log that said "preflight failed because origin was X but expected Y".

Any googling I do just seems to come up with either how to configure CORS or how to address specific problems.

The error Chrome was reporting was "No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource". But this question isn't about this error. The question is more general as in why the CORS preflight fails in general.

In this case, Chrome complained that 'Access-control-allow-origin' header wasn't set. I don't want this question to be about this specific error. Instead, what I want from this question is to determine if .NET Core has any logs that, using this case as an example, show WHY .NET Core did not include any Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

In this particular case, the URL used when configuring CORS was retrieved from an environment variable. I was deploying on a test server. The environment variable on the test server was incorrectly set to the URL for the integration environment. Because of this, .NET Core on the TEST server was expecting requests from the INT frontend. Because the requests were coming from the TEST frontend (test environment URL), it did not match what .NET Core was expecting (it was incorrectly expecting the requests to come from the INT url). Because of this, .NET Core did not include the 'Access-control-allow-origin' header.

Does .NET Core log this anywhere? Does it have any logs which tell me "Will not include 'Access-control-allow-origin' header in the response because the origin from the request is 'bla di bla' but 'lorem ipsum' was expected".

Code used

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other configurations...

    // Enable CORS with named policy
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            // Configure CORS policy as needed
            builder.WithOrigins(GetFrontendUrlFromEnvironmentVariable())
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
    // app.UseEndpoints( bla bla) and the rest;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error? What are you trying to do? The *browser* prevents scripts from making requests to other servers. CORS weakens the restriction by telling the browser what is allowed. It's not the server that refuses the call, it's the browser that, after inspecting the OPTIONS preflight check, refuses to make the call. The log you want is the browser's Network tab. The OPTIONS response contains the allowed origins, methods, headers etc.

Comment: Edited the question to answer your comment.

Comment: You've added a lot of extra text but no OPTIONS request or response, or Console log or code. . No code either. This is not about CORS in general. The OPTIONS response is the `Y was expected`. The *browser* verifies the request against the CORS headers, not .NET. `No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource"` means that the domain you tried to call isn't in the allowed list. You need to add it in your .NET code.

Comment: Is the real question how to verify that you've set up CORS correctly perhaps? That essentially asks how to test that you set your middleware correctly in Startup or Programs.cs. This isn't really about CORS. . If you don't add the CORS middleware how can there be any logs from it? You can test the CORS setup by creatin an integration test with [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and check whether OPTIONS requests return any headers.

Comment: There's no detailed logging in Startup.cs or Program.cs because logging itself isn't yet available. The logging middleware is getting configured along with the rest of the application. Once the pipeline is up and running, [CORS will log using ILogger](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b4d0e85805b84a65138e8e746d0cb65cd27a3858/src/Middleware/CORS/src/CORSLoggerExtensions.cs) in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` category. These are filtered out in most web apps because the default setup is to only log warnings from the `Microsoft` category.

Comment: The problem is that .NET's CORS middleware doesn't give enough context for browsers to issue a useful error message. Short of [improving the implementation](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#9-ease-troubleshooting-by-eschewing-shortcuts-during-preflight) of .NET's CORS middleware, you're unlikely to get more helpful error messages about your CORS issues.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You wrote: _No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource"._ I'm not sure about how .NET deals with this situation, but for most CORS middleware libraries, [it's not that simple](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#9-ease-troubleshooting-by-eschewing-shortcuts-during-preflight).

Comment: So many comments, so much info to take in (that's good :) ). @PanagiotisKanavos  "means that the domain you tried to call isn't in the allowed list. You need to add it in your .NET code." Ok, but wouldn't it be useful if .NET simply tells me this in a log as well as what is the list of domains it expects?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Is the real question how to verify that you've set up CORS correctly perhaps?" not really. It works on my dev machine just fine. I also have unit tests that again run just fine. The problem occurs when the code is deployed. I have no control over there. I can't check how the CICD guys configured env vars and so on.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "these are filtered out in most web apps because the default setup is to only log warnings from the Microsoft category". Then I guess perhaps this might be the problem. Do I have to change the log levels to see the CORS logs? At the moment I don't get anything.

Comment: @jub0bs Well, I don't mind that the browsers don't get enough info as long as I can get that info from the backend logs, which at the moment I am not getting. I guess there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @user1969903 no, that's not the problem and will only serve as an indicator that something may be wrong. It won't tell you what went wrong. Nor wil lit tell you that the wrong policies were configured. CORS happens on every `fetch` request so is *extremely* noisy and shouldn't be turned on. You configure logging the same way you do your any other source - by setting the log levels for specific categories.

Comment: @jub0bs I just had a thorough read through what you linked. Should you make a .NET CORS middleware, do let me know.

Comment: @user1969903 Thanks. I don't think I will ever work with .NET, but I encourage whoever is willing to draw inspiration from ideas laid out in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the real question is how to detect whether CORS was misconfigured. Logging can't show this. During setup in Program.cs or Startup.cs, the logging middleware itself isn't yet up.

Once the application starts, CORS does use logging, issuing [messages in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b4d0e85805b84a65138e8e746d0cb65cd27a3858/src/Middleware/CORS/src/CORSLoggerExtensions.cs) category. All except `FailedToSetCorsHeaders` are at `Information` or bellow though and filtered out by the `"Microsoft.AspNetCore":"Warning"` setting used by most web applications. The default logging settings in `appsettings.json` are :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

To enable more detailed logging one should add `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors":"Information"`. This will create a lot of noise though and shouldn't be used in production

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors":"Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This can help up to a point, as it reports the results of policy checks, not what is sent to the browser or how the browser responds to it. It won't log how the CORS policies were set up or what they were.

To fix the *original* problem, an application should set up bootstrap a bootstrap logger, ie a logger used only during configuration, and log the various setup steps. This becomes a lot easier if the various configuration parts are extracted in their own methods or even classes.

For example, using [a Serilog Bootstrap logger](https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/) and separate CORS methods for each scenario, the application can log which one was configured, along with any settings :

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console() // + file or centralized logging
    .CreateLogger();


IServiceCollection CorsForProduction(IServiceCollection services, string envronment, ...)
{
    Log.Information("CORS for Production with {setting}",new {Environment=environment,...});

    services.AddCors(options=>{
        ...
    });

    return services
}


IServiceCollection CorsForStaging(IServiceCollection services, string envronment, ...)
{
    Log.Information("CORS for Staging with {setting}",new {Environment=environment,...});

    services.AddCors(options=>{
        ....
    });

    return services
}
```

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing. First I disabled each policy one by one. allow all headers, then allow all methods, then allow all origins. I saw that when I allowed all origins, the requests started working, so I knew the origin must've been configured wrong. I then added a log to see what origin it was using and voila, the value was misconfigured. I was hoping there was a better way to do this without making changes and deploying 5 times and avoid this trial and error. Something like a simple log "incoming request has this origin but was expecting that origin". I guess not.

Comment: You don't have to deploy anywhere to test CORS - you can use an integration test with WebApplicationFactory or Playwright to check what's getting returned. As for the root problem, the configuration, you need to log the actual configuration operations. CORS logging happens only after the entire pipeline starts, because there's no logging middleware in `Startup`

Comment: "You don't have to deploy anywhere to test CORS" That's kind of the point, though. It works locally and unit tests pass. When it was deployed is when it didn't work. The idea was to have more info when an actual request was sent. Not during startup. I just want .NET to tell me when it gets an OPTIONS request "hey look, this request comes from origin "some-origin". you know what? we won't include the allow origin header because you configured cors to only allow "some-other-origin". and that's it. that's all I want. In fact, I don't want anything else. If the request was correct, no logs.

Comment: But I see that is not going to happen so I added my own logging.

Comment: I just showed you how to get those very CORS logs in this answer. I even linked to the list of those logs. The only thing you need to do is change the settings in your `appsettings.Development.json` or `.Staging.json`, not redeploy.  As for `That's kind of the point, though` you can use a custom`Origin` header in the requests.

Comment: I'll add "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors":"Information" to the json and see what I get.

Answer (score -1):

To enable CORS logging in .NET Core, you can add the following code to the ConfigureServices method in your Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other configurations...

    // Enable CORS with named policy
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            // Configure CORS policy as needed
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Other configurations...

    // Enable CORS middleware
    app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");

    // Other middleware and endpoints...
}
```

Comment: Which line of code enables CORS logging? This is more or less the code I am already using to configure CORS in the first place. I don't see any line that specifically enables logging. Is it enabled by default? If so, I can't find anything in my logs. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user1969903 CORS validation happens on the browser, not the server. Your log is F12, Network Tab. Only the Network tab shows the OPTIONS responses. Or you can enable request/response logging in general, but that is just noise compared to what your browser will show you

Comment: Yes but the OPTIONS response just tells me that the Access-control-allow-origin' header is missing. It does not tell me WHY. It does not tell me why that header was not added by .NET in the response.

Comment: Because you didn't add it in your code. Post your CORS configuration code