# how to fix Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request error in iis for .net 6

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have 2 applications, the first one is for ui, which I worked with Blazor, and the second one is for API, which I worked with .net 6.
When it is in debug mode, it works correctly, but when I put it on iis, it gives the following error. Both applications are in the same domain, but they have different subdomains.

[image]

error text is : Login_Register:1 Access to fetch at 'https://ajabk.************' from origin 'https://aja.************' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

my program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();


/*app.UseCors(x => x
     .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin  
     .AllowCredentials());*/

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHsts();
app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleWare>();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: What happens when you have CORS enabled? I think you need to enable CORS for it to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024030/r2018 When I activate cors, it gives an error inside the image

Comment: And, it works if you call the API via POSTMAN or Insomnia?

Comment: Could you create a minimal sample which can reproduce the issue for us, and don't forget hide the sensitive information. I am willing to check the issue when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware is wrong in your `Program.cs file`. [The correct order should be like below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order):

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHsts();
app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleWare>();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Move to here
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

//app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

If it still not works for you, you can [follow the steps to check CORS error details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76736275/7687666).

Comment: thank you for answer , i change program.cs but not working

Comment: @mohammadasadi could you follow my suggestion to check the cors error details