# axios network error even though there is a response

Tags: asp.net-core, axios, cors

When a request fails axios throws a network error. It should throw something like:

```
NOT OK Error: Request failed with status code XXX
```

And I should be able to access response from the error object but I can't because of this. But in the browser console there is a response. [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hykZG.jpg)

I tried send same request with curl and it did worked as expected.

```
ndak0ta@Alis-MacBook-Pro ~ % curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7064/Auth/login' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "userName": "manager",
  "password": "string"
}'
curl: (18) HTTP/2 stream 1 was reset
{"error":"Username or password is incorrect.", ...
```

My Axios instance:

```
const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
});

axios.interceptors.request.use((config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const token = storage.getToken();
  
  if (!config.headers) {
      return config;
  }

  if (token) {
    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  
  config.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
  return config;
});
```

My Cors settings:

```
public static void AddCustomCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: [Could you follow the suggestion to check the cors issue ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76736275)

Comment: I read the console outputs and nothing about Cors. It might be not about server it's more like client side problem. Because I recall there was no such problem before it was working as expected. Suddenly it starts to act like this.