# Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS Network Failure with ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently deployed an application which was working well on my local machine but when I deployed it to the server and tried to access the endpoints on Swagger, I get the following error response [image]

The application was developed with C#/ASP.Net Core 6 and deployed on an Ubuntu Linux server and the process managed with PM2 process manager.

I have moved it to another server and it is working well and returning the expected response but still not working on the first server where I encountered that error.

Please any guide to resolving this will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think the issue is with the password.  If you are using a Windows Credential it will not work on Linux.  Try using OAUTH2 which is supported on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: @jdweng the issue is not just about that particular endpoint. All endpoints are  having the same issue. I am not complaining of the inability to log in but that the API service is not erachable regardless of the fact that it is running when launched, no API request to any of the endpoints is working on this particular server, even on Windows server

Comment: What's the full error message in the Console tab in browser dev tools?

Comment: You have a credential issue.  What OS is your machines?  Is code working on Windows but not Linux?  Coor policy may not allow you do login with an unencrypted password.  You may need a credential where the password is encrypted.

Comment: Check the browser console and see what it reports in there. Also, I recommend ignoring most of the comments made by jdweng.

Comment: @Helen the error message in the console is "net::connection_reset"

Comment: @DavidG the error message on the browser console tab shows 
net::connection_reset

Comment: Hi Josh, please enable the [asp.net core logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [cors logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76736275/7687666).

Comment: Usually the cors error message inside the swagger, not correct. If the error message occurs in the previous middleware of the CORS middleware, the CORS error message will also be encountered.