# Angular 17 on debug mode CORS issue when user is not unauthorized

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have an Angular 17 app and an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I debug Angular in Visual Studio Code. When I run it locally with `ng s -o` and I login to the system, and navigate to a page where the logged in user does not have permission to view, and expect the `Access Denied` error. The server responds with 401 (I know it has to be 403).

Sample repo at [here](https://github.com/tnlthanzeel/NetBox.Admin-CORS-issue/tree/master)

Once the server returns the 401 the chrome console throws the

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:xxxxx/api/security/users?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1&searchQuery=' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> and then the unauthorized msg is logged to the console, like below

[image]

but, when the logged user has permission, then there is no issue. all works as expected.

Then I built the app in production mode and ran it locally putting the production files of angular in the wwwroot folder of the ASP.NET Core 8 Web API app and it works fine and I get the expected error msg. I have also checked the preflight request and all scenarios pass the preflight request. This issue on debug mode running on VS code is very weird in Angular 17.

I tested the permission issue on API with swagger and its working as expected too. Can anybody help, this seems with debug mode in Angular 17

Comment: Could you kindly [check the detailed logs about CORS in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76736275/7687666) ? By the way, you also need to share the code in your program.cs, and please don't forget to hide your sensitive information.

Comment: i event tried AllowAnyOrigin() and it still throws the CORS error when there is a forbidden response from the API

Comment: i will add sample repository where you can try the same

Comment: @JasonPan, here is the repo. please read the readme https://github.com/tnlthanzeel/NetBox.Admin-CORS-issue/tree/master

Comment: Please give me some time and let me check it.

Comment: yes , please check and update !! will be a great  help!!

Comment: It's a huge project, maybe you used a Role before, you can see the answer, the old code that was left over from before needs to be replaced with `[Authorize(policy: ApplicationAuthPolicy.Settings.Services.View)]` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

It caused by middleware order and mssing `app.UseRouting();`.

If using below code, the error is same. Not port `4200` are `cors` and `401`, another is `403`.

**Excepted behavior**

[image]

```
var app = builder.Build();

{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(_ => { });

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) { }

    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            c.EnablePersistAuthorization();
        }
        else
        {
            c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new SubmitMethod[] { });
        }

        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        c.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);

    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    // app.UseOutputCache();

    app.MapControllers();//.RequireAuthorization();
    app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notify");//.RequireAuthorization();

    app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

}

app.Run();
```

---

Find the `ServiceTypesController.cs` file and comment this line `[Authorize(Roles ="NoEntry")]`. Like below:

```
[HttpGet]
//[Authorize(Roles ="NoEntry")]
[Authorize(policy: ApplicationAuthPolicy.Settings.Services.View)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseResult<IReadOnlyList<ServiceTypeDto>>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetServiceTypes([FromQuery] Paginator paginator, [FromQuery] ServiceTypeFilter filter, CancellationToken token)
{
    var response = await _serviceTypeService.GetServiceTypes(paginator, filter, token);

    return response.Success ? Ok(response) : UnsuccessfulResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: i added it on purpose so that u can easy recreate the issue. the issue is when u run on 4200 for angular. but if u builtd and copy the dist files into wwwroot of the web ap there is no issue.

Comment: Hi @thanzeel,I get your point, will update the answer tomorrow, please be patient.

Comment: Hi @thanzeel, just now I found your azurewebsites and test it, it's working and no 403 issue. Any updates ?

Comment: @thanzeel can your describe the details how to reproduce the issue(I mean which attribute should I use), I am confusing now.

Comment: you can just add the `[Authorize(Roles ="NoEntry")]` and remove `[Authorize(policy: ApplicationAuthPolicy.Settings.Services.View)]`. and try with port 4200 for angular, then it will throw the CORS issue. but with the same setup build the angular and get the prod files from dist and paste in `wwwroot` of API project and run from there, then no issue

Comment: @thanzeel I get you, checking...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256952/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-thanzeel).

Comment: @thanzeel I think I found the issue.