ASP.NET Core WebAPI error "Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code"
I have a .NET 8 application which is split into a Blazor wasm frontend and an aps.net core webapi both hosted in azure. On some rare occasions, http requests get denied by the backend which looks like the following to the client:

The german error text translates to “Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource”. But since the request is successful on another try, I figured that it is not a CORS issue and that’s when I checked the server logs for this http request:

After finishing the http request pipeline, there is another log entry which says “Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code”. But the strange thing is that is was being handled by the controller action (“Executed action” and “Executed endpoint” was logged before). Even though I am missing a log entry from the entity framework database query.
To make it even more complicated, the exact same request works for like 99% of the time. Only on rare occasions (a few times a month), there is this error “Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code”.
I can’t reproduce the error as it is not related to

the endpoint being called
the date or time
the client or his browser

Maybe you have some more ideas to check for. Thanks in advance
As this is related to the http pipeline, here is my definition:
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

//.NET Aspire health checks
app.MapDefaultEndpoints(); 

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRequestLocalization();

app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

app.MapControllers();

await app.RunAsync();


Cannot reproduce it ,are you meaning it is a sporadic issue ? Have you tried locally and what is the behavior?

Yes it is a sporadic issue only appearing a few times per month on the Azure environment. I can't reproduce it and it never happend during local development.

There are some misconfigurations you need to pay attention to.  First, the order of your middleware is wrong. app.UseCors(); should be set after useRouting and before useAuthorization. app.MapDefaultEndpoints(); should be set after MapControllers. Second, enable logging both on middleware and application level, which is the middleware log and the asp.net core log. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76735594/how-to-diagnose-cors-issues-in-net-core-5/76736275#76736275   Then check if it still happens sometimes.

@FengzhiZhou I followed your advises and will update you in a month or so whether it was successful. Sporadic errors suck :(
